# Reference constraint in oauth table Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.6

I have 2 tables. User Table and Role Table in migration folder. Also installed Laravel Passport

When I ran this command `php artisan migrate`, I saw the auth tables created first and then role table and user table.

Can I run role and user table first because I want to put reference constraints in auth table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact stuff Laravel Passport does, but in general the Migrator classes are ran in alphabetic order. Given the fact that they are prefixed with the generation timestamp, it should be enough just renaming the role migrator, to having a timstamp before the user migrator.

When you do this, don't forget to regenerate the autoload files.

Comment: ant idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075974/laravel-5-6-passport-driver-not-working-in-socket-io-and-gives-unauthorized-exce

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Migration run on the alpahbetical order .

Consider an example where you Auth table with the migration named as

```
2018_03_18_12_create_auth_tables.php
```

User table migration as

```
2018_03_18_13_create_users_tables.php
```

In this case the Auth table will run first and User table will run second due to their alpahbetical order . If you want to change the order of the migration then you can rename the file of users table as

```
2018_03_18_11_create_users_tables.php
```

After doing this the alphabetical order will change and the users table will run first.

I hope this helps